How could I create a textBox or a selectBox in the Summary
I have a datagrid from devextreme reactjs, Which is basically renders the provided as shown below. So While doing that I got set a search Box in the Summary area or below the column. How could I do that
code snippest
 <DataGrid noDataText='No Data Available!!!'
                dataSource={tokenList}
                showBorders={true}
            >
                <Paging defaultPageSize={5} />
                <Pager
                    visible={true}
                    displayMode="full"
                    showInfo={true}
                    showPageSizeSelector={true} />

                <Column dataField="tokenNum" caption={formatMessage('Token_Number')} allowEditing={false} alignment='left' />
                <Column dataField="truckNum" caption={formatMessage('Truck_Number')} allowEditing={false} alignment='left' />
                <Column dataField="friendlyName" caption={formatMessage('Friendly_Name')} allowEditing={false} alignment='left' />
                <Column dataField="commodityname" caption={formatMessage('Commodity')} allowEditing={false} alignment='left' />
                <Column dataField="noofbags" caption={formatMessage('No_Of_Bags')} allowEditing={false} alignment='left' />
                <Column dataField="transactiontype" caption={formatMessage('Transaction_Type')} allowEditing={false} alignment='left' />
                <Column dataField="tokenIssuedOn" caption={formatMessage('Token_Issue_Date')} allowEditing={false} alignment='left' />
                <Column dataField="tokenStatus" caption={formatMessage('Status')} allowEditing={false} alignment='left' />

                <Column
                    allowSorting={false}
                    caption="#"
                    cellRender={(rowData) => shouldRender(rowData.data)}
                />
                {/* TODO : need to create a search pannels and select pannel for this part */}
            </DataGrid>

I try to add GroupItem and then add NumberBox into it but it's not working as intended. As a matter of fact the NumberBox is not displaying.

Have you tried using the FilterRow property in devextreme Data Grid?

@hokwanhung, Bro I had tried it But couldn't able to load the select-box(neglecting the positions).

The default select-boxes will show when you hover over the magnifying glass with the default FilterRow component. But if you want to use customized components, cellRender in Columns accepts returning another component inside. Please show more codes with the shouldRender() function you have, and the panels you want.

But @hokwanhung when I try cellRender, It is creating a set of selectBoxes in the column. You can see in the Image the searchpannels are at the bottom. If i do use filterRow I can't able to render that searchpannels at the bottom. Since they only work in headers only.

Yeah, I also agree that the cellRender property should work the closest to what you expected; the remaining issue is updating the data with the search boxes.

Would it be possible for you to provide the codes in shouldRender() to create search boxes? It is fine if it is not available; should be able to provide an answer later.

Above is the max I can share. The thing is I want all the filterRow components be at the summary part.
